# How to protect website from malicious scripts?

Tags: php

Two day ago my website was banned by all browsers because there were some malicious script at the very top of my index.php file. I have no idea where this script came from. Removed it several times but it appears again after several hours. I have already contacted my hosting provider and the only advice from them was to change the password. Although that didn't solve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: This could be anything. There are a million different places where you may have an exploitable security hole.

Comment: There are whole books written on this topic.  It's far too broad a question to expect anyone to answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have most likely been hacked. Somebody found a little backdoor in your php scripts which he exploited to gain access to your files.

I suggest as a first step you read the very basic documentation here: [php security manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.php)
and then continue with other resources on the internet. Php security is not to be taken lightly as it can compromise your whole website (as it is your case)

Answer (score 0):

Of course that could be anything. One thing that no one probably will say here but it might be the case, is that you might be using Total Commander to update your site and you have checked "remember password" checkbox. There used to be a security whole in this program and it happened to me many years (like 4) ago that my index.php files were infected with iframe due to this. As the solution I have switched to FileZilla (but unchecking "remember password" should also work and of course changing password.

Answer (score 0):

Instead FTP, better use SFTP access. This can be enabled in your cpanel. For queries in SFTP enabling, read the help documents provided by your hosting company.

Till enabling SFTP, better change password with mixed AplhaNumeric & Special Characters. Stop accessing your site using FTP via Filezilla. Change the default file permissions to 444.